# Wordpress: On login send to pages list rather than dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function that will allow you to change where you get redirected to once logged in?

I'm logging into the standard Wordpress login form which redirects you to the dashboard, is there a way to change it so you get redirected to the pages list?

**It's important that I'm not editing core WP files (although easy, it's asking for trouble!) and doing this via a function.**

This isn't any kind of front end log in, it's all backend just redirecting the standard WP login screen from the dashboard to the pages list - wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page (as I don't like the info displayed on the dashboard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your theme functions.php:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return home_url(); //admin redirect url
        } else {
            return admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); //user redirect url
        }
    }
    else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

This will redirect the user back to the homepage once logged in. With the above you can redirect administrators to a seperate location (dashboard if need be) and then the rest of your users to your custom url.

Comment: Thanks. Is that all purely backend? I just want the user to goto this page - /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

Comment: You've returned `home_url()` on both events.

Comment: @RRikesh Also, I'm not sure it's answered the question - see last paragraph.

Comment: i have edited my answer. So now the user will get redirected to  /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page'; and the admin goes to your homepage

Comment: Use `admin_url()` to construct urls pointing to wp admin: `admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );`